# I can't post because it says: "This post does not meet our quality standards." Where are the quality standards explained?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask: "Is there a version or analogue of Gibbard's theorem for voters with cardinal utility functions?" but I can't.

What should I do?

Where can I read the quality standards?

Why isn't this error message more informative?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for coming to our community. The filter that is blocking your post is set at a global level by the Stack Exchange network, and is not under the control of the Economics Stack Exchange community. You can read more about the filter here, including the kinds of things that can trigger this message:

[What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar)